# Count number of vector values in range with R

Tags: r, vector, comparison

In R, if you test a condition on a vector instead of a scalar, it will return a vector containing the result of the comparison for each value in the vector. For example...

```
> v <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> v > 2
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

In this way, I can determine the number of elements in a vector that are above or below a certain number, like so.

```
> sum(v > 2)
[1] 3
> sum(v < 2)
[1] 1
```

Does anyone know how I can determine the number of values in a given range? For example, how would I determine the number of values greater than 2 but less than 5?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try

```
> sum(v > 2 & v < 5)
```

Comment: That was so easy I'm embarrassed. The first thing I tried was something like that, except I used && as the logical and operator instead of &. I'm just so used to using it in other languages. What is the difference between '&' and '&&' in R?

Comment: && is used for vectors of length 1. & operates on each element in a vector.

Comment: Is there any simple way to ignore NA values with such code?

Comment: @Slam, simply use `sum(v > 2 & v < 5, na.rm=T)` to remove NAs.

Answer (score 4):

There are also the %<% and %<=% comparison operators in the TeachingDemos package which allow you to do this like:

```
sum( 2 %<% x %<% 5 )
sum( 2 %<=% x %<=% 5 )
```

which gives the same results as:

```
sum( 2 < x & x < 5 )
sum( 2 <= x & x <= 5 )
```

Which is better is probably more a matter of personal preference.

Comment: That is definitely helpful. I tried something like that but got syntax errors. That's how I would write in on paper or LaTeX, so it's good to know. By the way, I assume you meant x %<=% 5 and not x %<= 5%.

Comment: Thanks for catching the % that tried to float away, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

Use which:

```
 set.seed(1)
 x <- sample(10, 50, replace = TRUE)
 length(which(x > 3 & x < 5))
 # [1]  6
```