# finding values in a range in r and sum the number of values

Tags: r

I have a question I have the following data

```
 c(1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 8, 9)
```

I set a l = 2 and an u = 6

I want to find all the values in the range (3,7)

How can I do this?

Comment: The sum part of your question is handled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3818147/5325862)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R` we can use comparison operators to create a logical vector and use that for subsetting the original vector

```
x[x > 2 & x <= 6]
#[1] 3 5 6
```

---

Or using a `for` loop, initialize an empty vector, loop through the elements of 'x', `if` the value is between 2 and 6, then concatenate that value to the empty `vector`

```
v1 <- c()
for(i in x) {
   if(i > 2 & i <= 6) v1 <- c(v1, i)
   }

v1
#[1] 3 5 6
```

#### data

```
x <- c(3, 5, 6, 8, 1, 2, 1)
```

Comment: how can I do this in a forloop?

Comment: @user8959427 why would you need a `for` loop? In R we try to avoid them as they are less efficient compared to vectorized operations

Comment: @user8959427  Updated with a `for` loop

Comment: `x[x %in% (i+1):(j)]`

Comment: Also, `x[findInterval(x, c(-Inf, i, j), left.open = TRUE) == 2]`